# How can I add more than 1 filter to persistence manager query in Java Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, persistence

I'm using Java servlets to develop a Google App Engine application. I need to write up a query with more than 1 condition in the where clause. The commented out line below gives me query_parsing error. Is there a way to add more than one condition in the where clause?

```
String query = "select from " + Human.class.getName();
query += " where name == '" + request.getParameter("name") + "'";
//query += " and lastname == '" + request.getParameter("lastname") + "'";
List<Human> humans = (List<Human>) pm.newQuery(query).execute();
```

I know this is possible with JDO queries such as the below. However, my version is different. I'm using a String object to write up the query and then execute it with persistence manager (Please see above).

```
Query query = pm.newQuery(Employee.class);
query.setFilter("lastName == lastNameParam");
query.setOrdering("hireDate desc");
query.declareParameters("String lastNameParam");
```

Comment: Don't assemble query strings from user data - this is _asking_ for injection vulnerabilities! JDO provides a mechanism for named parameters (http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/queries.html) - use it!

Answer (score 1):

In your first code snippet, I believe the issue is the word 'and', which should be '&&'.  To have multiple filters, as in your second snippet, you would also use the '&&' operator.

```
String query = "select from " + Human.class.getName();
query += " where name == '" + request.getParameter("name") + "'";
query += " && lastname == '" + request.getParameter("lastname") + "'";
List<Human> humans = (List<Human>) pm.newQuery(query).execute();
```

or

```
Query query = pm.newQuery(Employee.class);
query.setFilter("lastName == lastNameParam && name == nameParam");
query.setOrdering("hireDate desc");
query.declareParameters("String lastNameParam");
query.declareParameters("String nameParam");
```